# Service to convert URL content to JSON?

Tags: json, github

Is there some free service that will *jsonify* the content at a URL?
Namely I am trying to convert specific source files at Github into JSON.

Comment: What's the purpose of this conversion? What json output do you expect? A simple `{"content":"..."}` or something useful?

Comment: @CodesInChaos your example is fine. The reason I need this is that I want to parse the specific source files in Javascript to create documentation. I work in a big company so doing this the normal way is a no-no.